# График matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Как можно отрисовать подобный график? То есть чтобы после определенного значения Х можно было поменять цвет, тип линии и добавить еще линии
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такие "составные графики" проще всего рисовать как два разных графика -  т.е. предварительно  разбив исходный график на две части.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(0,2,100)
y=np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x[0:50],y[0:50],c='b',linewidth=1)
plt.plot(x[50:],y[50:],c='g',linewidth=5)
y3=0.5*np.sin(x)+0.4
plt.plot(x[50:],y3[50:],':',c='r',linewidth=3)
plt.vlines(1, 0, 1)
```

Есть и другие, более изощренные способы, но это самый простой и прямой.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]